# What is "Lifetime Intensity" in photoluminescence?

Tags: photons, terminology, spectroscopy, molecules, photon-emission

I'm reading an article "Surface plasmon enhanced Förster resonance energy transfer between the
CdTe quantum dots". [Link](http://www.tara.tcd.ie/xmlui/bitstream/handle/2262/31148/Surface%20plasmon.pdf?sequence=1)

The reasearchers are writing about increase in "lifetime intensity" and even plot this on a diagram. However I don't know what is "lifetime intensity". I know what lifetime AND intensity are. Does this even make sense?

Can someone help me, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it's the integral of intensity over time.

$$\text{Lifetime intensity}=\int_0^\infty{I(t)dt}$$

"Intensity" in the instantaneous light output - the total light you get is that intensity from excitation until final decay.

That said - it seems that the figure 2 in the paper you referenced in your link is using inconsistent labeling - because in the inset they plot "lifetime intensity" as a function of number of PET bilayers, yet in the main plot they plot "something" (that they call "lifetime intensity") as a function of time. I believe that plot is mislabeled. So much for peer review...